# How to avoid Array-Like behavior in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase works in this way:

```
// we send this
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}

// since the keys are numeric and sequential,
// if we query the data, we get this
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

// however, if we then delete a, b, and d,
// they are no longer mostly sequential, so
// we do not get back an array
{2: 'c', 4: 'e'}
```

Check more about it here: http://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Do you know how to avoid this weird behavior?
I want to save `{0:91, 1: 99, 2: 998}` and get exactly what I saved. I don't want the array `[91, 99, 998]` I want `{0:91, 1: 99, 2: 998}`.

This is the code that I use to save:

```
// This is goig to add a new key in the object
app.post('/push/another/value', (req, res) => {
  admin.database()
    .ref('/games/').child(req.body.gameId)
    .child('/solved/').child(req.body.i).set(req.body.newValue);
});
```

And this is the code to get it:

```
app.post('/get/all/values', (req, res) => {
  admin.database().ref('/games/').child(req.body.gameId)
    .once('value').then(value => {
      let game = value.val();

      game.solved = game.solved || {};

      res.send({
        status: 'ok',
        data: {
          game: game
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: The Firebase JS SDK is now open source and you can find the `val()` implementation [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/v4.5.1/packages/database/src/core/snap/ChildrenNode.ts#L200-L230). You'll see that it treats snapshots with all integer keys, where the max key is less than double the number of keys, as arrays. This is reasonably deep in the `DataSnapshot` implementation, so I'm not sure what supplies the `exportFormat` parameter. Maybe you can do some digging?

Comment: What is your code that's loading and saving the values you're showing?

Comment: @DougStevenson I just added the code to the answer.

Comment: What exactly is req.body.newValue?

Comment: @DougStevenson is a number. Not a string. These numbers are being saved perfectly. The problem is the "array-like" behavior that is explained in the link

Comment: If you don't want to send the array, the convert it to an object or whatever you want before sending.  You can't change the behavior of the SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson That's what I'm doing right now, but it feels like an ugly method. Anyways, I hope to have a better way to do it ASAP. Thanks!